# Вопрос по размеру файлов в Linux

Tags: linux, c

Вот [здесь](http://devtype.blogspot.ru/2016/05/Osnovy-programmirovanija-dlja-Linux.html) встретилась такая фраза:

Файлы, содержащие 1 байт и 20 байт будут иметь при хранении на диске один и тот же размер.

Как это правильно понимать и почему это так? Спасибо.

Comment: Я бы сказал, не "будут иметь один размер", а "занимать одно и то же место на диске"...

Comment: Все дело в файловой системе.

Comment: @Harry, не факт, кстати. Для развенчивания мифов о файловых системах можно обратиться к pifs. Идея там проста, и фактически место, "занимаемое" на носителе определяется не искомым размером файла, а его содержимым (положением).

Answer (score 7):

Файлы на диске храняться не в чистых виде, а в так называемых "кластерах" - блоках определенного объема. И "пол блока" занимать нельзя).
Для сравнения можно представить бутылки с водой.
Вот допустим у нас есть куча литровых бутылок. И больше ничего. При этом если мы хотим взять с собой стакан чая. Он будет занимать литровую бутылку (и пофиг что его там всего 200 грамм). Еще литр сока? Еще бутылка. Еще полтора литра лимонада? Это еще две бутылки по литру.
Как так и с файлами. Любой файл полностью занимает какое то количество полных кластеров.
1 байт = 1 кластер. 20 байт = 1 кластер.
Ну а размер этих кластеров зависит от файловой системы и её настроек.

Comment: Чушь. Если вы про логические странички внутри накопителя (секторы), то ещё куда ни шло, но файловая система -- это абстракция над блоками, которыми оперирует накопитель. Поэтому занимаемое место на диске файлом определяется исключительно файловой системой. При её отсутствии -- логическими блоками накопителя. Что такое *кластер* -- остаётся загадкой.

Comment: Кластер (англ. cluster) — в некоторых типах файловых систем логическая единица хранения данных в таблице размещения файлов, объединяющая группу секторов. Например, на дисках с размером секторов в 256 байт, 256-байтный кластер содержит один сектор, тогда как 2-килобайтный кластер содержит восемь секторов.

Как правило, это наименьшее место на диске, которое может быть выделено для хранения файла.
Понятие кластер используется в файловых системах FAT, NTFS, a так же HFS Plus. Другие файловые системы оперируют схожими понятиями (зоны в Minix, блоки в Unix). (с)Гугл).

Comment: Спасибо за ликбез!

Answer (score 4):

Файлы, содержащие 1 байт или 20 байт будут иметь размер 1 и 20 байт соответственно, если вы не используете какое-то свое, неортодоксальное понятие *размера файла*.

Сколько места такие файлы будут "отнимать" на физическом носителе информации зависит от используемой данным носителем файловой системы и от более низкоуровневых вопросов организации самого носителя. Так что ваше "в Linux" тут совершенно сбоку припеку. Файловая система файловой системе рознь. Носитель носителю рознь.

И раз уж вы зачем-то поставили в своем вопросе таг [C]: в языке С концепция *файла* не предполагает/не гарантирует наличия у файла некоего предопределенного размера.

Comment: Считаете libc/stdio.h (FILE \*) тоже часть языка?

Comment: @avp: Да, конечно.